# Declaring an Array in my Model to use in the Control

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm new to Objective-C and MVC. Ive been following along with Paul Haggerty's Coursework and lectures and learned a lot. I am entering a phase in my programming that I am actually able to sit down and code working apps rather than solely reading about iOS development.

I'm having difficulty understanding the how to use MVC properly.

Here is the (VERY BASIC) code that I've written and got to "work":

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked {
    NSArray *namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (NSString *)@"Tiffany",
                           (NSString *)@"Jason",
                           (NSString *)@"Mustafa",
                           (NSString *)@"Mellisa",
                           (NSString *)@"Michael",
                           (NSString *)@"Kasim",
                           nil];

    if ([self.myDisplay.text
         isEqualToString:[namesArray objectAtIndex:0]]){
        self.myDisplay.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:1];
    } else if ([self.myDisplay.text 
         isEqualToString:[namesArray objectAtIndex:1]]){
        self.myDisplay.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:2];
    } else if ([self.myDisplay.text 
         isEqualToString:[namesArray objectAtIndex:2]]){
        self.myDisplay.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:3];
    } else if ([self.myDisplay.text 
         isEqualToString:[namesArray objectAtIndex:3]]){
        self.myDisplay.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:4]; 
    } else if ([self.myDisplay.text 
         isEqualToString:[namesArray objectAtIndex:4]]){
        self.myDisplay.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:5];
    } else {
        self.myDisplay.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    self.numberOfLetters.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Letters", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.myDisplay.text.length - 1]];
 }
```

As you can see it sets up an array and then when the user clicks the button on screen it displays the next name and the number of letters in that name. What I want to do is create my Array in my model and then access it through the controller (that's what you're supposed to do right?)

My approach to it was to create a model class (which i called Brain). I imported the brain into the controller and in the brain I created an NSArray property and synthesized it. But I'm having difficulty accessing it in the controller.

Also, I know that the way I have it done now is wrong because I'm basically recreating the array every time the user clicks the button.

Can someone please guide me? (I'm using ARC, btw.)

Here is how I created my Brain" class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Brain : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myNamesArray;

@end

#import "Brain.h"

@implementation Brain
@synthesize myNamesArray = _myNamesArray;

@end
```

Comment: Show the interface and implementation for your Brain class to give people a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just keep track of the index. Define it as a property in your class header. Also, you probably don't want to keep creating new arrays.

```
@property (nonatomic) int index;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *namesArray;
```

Synthesize it in your implementation:

```
@synthesize index, namesArray;
```

Create the array in your init method (or viewDidLoad method if you prefer):

```
self.namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"Tiffany",
                       @"Jason",
                       @"Mustafa",
                       @"Mellisa",
                       @"Michael",
                       @"Kasim",
                       nil];
```

If you're not using ARC, be sure to release namesArray in the dealloc method.

Then just use that to set the text string.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked {
    self.index++;
    self.myDisplay.text = [self.namesArray objectAtIndex:index%[namesArray count]];
}
```

Comment: did you mean to add this code to the controller or the model? it seems Im adding this to the controller.... I may have to review MVC concepts again to achieve clarity...

Comment: It's perfectly fine to add this code to your view controller. If the model were getting more complex or loading from another source such as a web service, then I would consider separating it out. But for something this trivial, no need.

Comment: If you were going to create a model class for this example, you might call it PeopleModel (for example) and it would be implemented with most of the same code as above. It could have a single public method defined, such as "nextName" and its implementation would be nicely encapsulated from the controller. But again, that's the difference between theory and practice. :)

Comment: okay I see now. So, your saying that as long the application is small enough, it is okay to just program in the controller and if the application is complex then one should definitely switch to incorporating a model?